# Probability distribution of the infinity norm of a Gaussian vector

Tags: normed-spaces, confidence-interval, gaussian

Let $N \geq 1$ be an integer.

Let $X$ be a standard $\mathbb{R}^N$ Gaussian vector (all components are $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and i. i. d.).

Let $A \in \mathcal{M}_N(\mathbb{R})$ be a deterministic matrix.

Thus, $AX$ is a Gaussian vector.

Let $\epsilon \in (0, 1)$.

I would like to simulate Gaussian *vectors* of the form $AX$ that *mostly have a smaller infinity norm* than $\epsilon$, with only controlling the *infinity norm of the matrix* $A$.

So the question is: how to limit $||A||_{\infty} = \underset{i, j}{\max} |A_{i, j}|$ so that with high confidence / probability (let's say 95%), I get $||AX||_{\infty} \leq \epsilon$ ?

I am looking for an answer like: **take $A$ such that $||A||_{\infty} \leq f(\epsilon)$**. The answer is quite easy in the $1$-dimensional case, I would like to generalize it, but haven't found any clear theorem addressing that.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some $n$ ($1$, $2$ and all multiples of $4$ if you admit a certain conjecture; all powers of $2$ if you don't), we can find explicitely the best bound.

Notwithstanding this conjecture, we find for $f(\varepsilon)$ a rate of convergence of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n\log (n)}}$, less conservative than $\frac{1}{n}$.

---

We will denote by $X_0$ a standardized normal law $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ independent (jointly) from our variables.

> **Lemma 1:** for all $\varepsilon>0, r>0$, $\min \limits_{A \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R}),\ ||A||_{\infty} \le r} \mathbb{P}\big(||AX||_{\infty} \le \varepsilon\big) \ge \mathbb{P}\big(|X_0| \le \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{n}r}\big)^n$

The proof if a direct application of the [Gaussian correlation inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_correlation_inequality).

*Proof:* let $A \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ with $||A||_{\infty} \le r$. Then, for $i \in [\![1,n]\!]$, the region defined by $\big|(Ax)_i\big| \le \varepsilon$ is convex and symmetric about the origin. Thus $\mathbb{P}\big(||AX||_{\infty} \le \varepsilon \big) \ge \prod \limits_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}\big(|(AX)_i| \le \varepsilon\big)$. Also, $(AX)_i \sim \mathcal{N}\big(0, \sum \limits_{j=1}^n a_{i,j}^2\big)$, so $\mathbb{P}\big(|(AX)_i| \le \varepsilon\big) = \mathbb{P}\Big(|X_0| \le \varepsilon / \sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^n a_{i,j}^2}\Big) \ge \mathbb{P}\big(|X_0| \le \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{n}r}\big)$ since $||A||_{\infty}  \le r$.

$ $

What this lemma says, is that the matrices $A$ for which we have the lowest confidence are the ones with

- uncorrelated outputs for $AX$, so orthogonal lines for $A$
- coefficients which are close (in absolute value) to $||A||_{\infty}$

These two properties bring us to the next section: we can find matrices satisfying these conditions, and reaching the bound of lemma $1$.

---

A [Hadamard matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_matrix) of order $n$ is a matrix $H_n \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ with coefficients $+1$ or $-1$, such that $HH^T = nI_n$. While the construction of Hadamard matrix of order $2^k$ is obvious, a stil standing conjecture is:

> **Conjecture:** for $n=1,2$ or any multiple of $4$, there exists a Hamadard matrix or order $n$.

Now why were we talking about Hadamard matrices again? That is because they are the worst case matrices for your problem:

> **Lemma 2:** given a Hadamard matrix $H_n$, for $A = rH_n$ the bound of lemma $1$ is reached: $$\min \limits_{A \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R}),\ ||A||_{\infty} \le r} \mathbb{P}\big(||AX||_{\infty} \le \varepsilon\big) = \mathbb{P}\big(||rH_nX||_{\infty} \le \varepsilon\big) = \mathbb{P}\big(|X_0| \le \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{n}r}\big)^n$$

*Proof:* let us denote $A = rH_n$. Since the rows of $H_n$ are orthogonal, the $(AX)_i$ are uncorrelated, and as $AX$ is a gaussian vector, the $(AX)_i$ are independent. Thus $\mathbb{P}\big(||AX||_{\infty} \le \varepsilon\big) = \prod \limits_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}\big(|(AX)_i| \le \varepsilon\big)$. Last, the coefficients of $A$ are either $r$ or $-r$, so $(AX)_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, nr^2)$, and thus
$\mathbb{P}\big(||AX||_{\infty} \le \varepsilon\big) = \mathbb{P}\big(|X_0| \le \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{n}r}\big)^n$.

---

Conclusion: for all $n$, you can take $$f(\varepsilon) = \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{n} \cdot F^{-1}\big(\frac{1+\alpha^{1/n}}{2}\big)}$$

with $F$ the cdf of $X_0$, to get $||AX||_{\infty} \le \varepsilon$ for all $A$ with $||A||_{\infty} \le f(\varepsilon)$, with confidence level at least $\alpha$, and exactly $\alpha$ for those $n$ for which a Hadamard matrix exist.

Using [the asymptotics of $F^{-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2964944/asymptotics-of-inverse-of-normal-cdf), as $n \to +\infty$ you can take $f(\varepsilon) = \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{n \log\big(\frac{4n^2}{\log(\alpha)^2}\big)}}$.

---

Answer (score 2):

I doubt, that there is an exact formula to do this (that is if we want exactly 95% confidence and not just at least 95% confidence). For instance consider the two matrices
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \quad , \quad B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$
These matrices satisfy $||A||_\infty = 1 =||B||_\infty$, but clearly $||Ax||_{\infty} \leq ||Bx||_\infty$, thus matrices of the form $B$ would give larger confidence intervals.

The alternative is to give an upper bound for $||AX||_\infty$, and then establish a rule that gives the desired result with at least 95% confidence. One possibility is to use that

$$||AX||_\infty^2 \leq ||AX||_2^2 \leq n^2||A||_\infty^2||X||_2^2$$
so we can say that
$$\mathbb{P}(||AX||_\infty < \epsilon) \geq \mathbb{P}(n^2||A||_\infty^2||X||_2^2 < \epsilon^2) = \mathbb{P}(||X||_2^2 < \frac{\epsilon^2}{n^2||A||_\infty^2})$$
But since $||X||_2^2$ is a sum of squared $i.i.d.$ $N(0,1)$ variables it has a $\chi^2$ distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom, and thus in order to get at least 95% confidence, we could choose $\frac{\epsilon}{n^2||A||_\infty^2}$ to be the $0.95$'th quantile of the $\chi^2(n)$ distribution. That is we require $||A||_\infty^2=\frac{\epsilon^2}{n^2 q}$, where $q$ is the said quantile so you could choose your function $f$ as
$$f(\epsilon)= \frac{\epsilon}{n \sqrt{q}}$$

Another possibly better bound would be $||AX||_\infty \leq n ||A||_\infty ||X||_\infty$, but this requires that we know the distribution of $||X||_\infty$, which is a bit more complicated but possible.

Comment: Remark: I came up with this method myself as i found your question interesting. I haven't  tried it in practice, and it might be that the method might be too conservative (give too high confidence levels) especially when $n$ becomes large.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. In fact, I wasn't absolutely sure of finding an exact solution. Do you have references for the distribution of $||X||_\infty$? And a website where I can easily compute the quantiles of the $\chi^2$ distribution?

Comment: Maybe the bound $||AX||_\infty \leq ||A||_\infty \cdot ||X||_1$ is interesting.

Comment: I usually use RStudio for statistics related computations. If you don't want to download and install the program, then i found this online editor https://rextester.com/l/r_online_compiler
simply type:
qchisq(0.95, df = n)
to get 0.95 quantile with n degrees of freedom.

Comment: Note that $||X||_\infty = max(|X_1|, \dots , |X_n|)$ where $X_1,\dots, X_n$ are i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ distributed. The CDF for $|X_1|$ is $2\Phi(x)-1$ for $x>0$, and thus the CDF for $||X||_\infty$ is $(2\Phi(x)-1)^n$. $\Phi$ is the CDF of N(0,1).

Comment: Oh.. $||A||_\infty \cdot ||X||_1$ is a much better bound, since it doesn't give the factor of $n$. So instead we would need to calculate the distribution of $||X||_1=\sum_i |X_i|$, but this is a sum of $i.i.d.$ variables, so for large $n$ we can approximate the distribution as $$N( n \cdot \sqrt{2/\pi}  , n\sigma^2)$$, since $\mathbb{E}[|X_1|] = \sqrt{2/\pi}$.

Comment: Then, for large $n$, one would have that the law of $||A||_\infty \cdot ||X||_1$ is approximately $\mathcal{N}(||A||_{\infty} n \sqrt{\tfrac{2}{\pi}}, ||A||_{\infty} n \sigma^2)$. And I would have to compute $1$-dimensional quantiles of a normal law, that's it? Thanks a lot.