What is the value of $\lim_{x \to 0} \Phi^{-1}(x) - \Phi^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)$?
Denote by $\Phi^{-1}$ the inverse normal cdf. I want to calculate the following limit:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \Phi^{-1}(x) - \Phi^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right).$$
I think it should be $0$ but I am not able to prove it. Can someone help me?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Note that $\Phi^{-1}(0) = -\infty$.

Does this help? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2966269/27150

@preferred_anon So if I am correct I can rewrite the limit as follows ?
$$ \lim_{y \to 0} -\sqrt{-2\log(y)} + \sqrt{-2\log\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)}$$

@Abezhiko The problem is that the limit is of the form $-\infty + \infty$ and so of undefined form.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. I think you mean $\lim_{x\to0^+}$.

Is the following equivalent (using Mathematica notation):  Limit[InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 1/10^x] -    InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], (1/10^x)/2], x -> \[Infinity]]. That results in a value of 0.  This is replacing $x$ by $1/10^x$ with $x -> \infty$.

@JimB. Just kidding : There are $\huge 0$, $\large 0$, $0$, $\small 0$

Around $x=0$
$$\Phi^{-1}(x)=-\sqrt{a-\log (a)}\qquad \text{with} \qquad a= -\log \left(2 \pi  x^2\right)$$
The required difference seems to be difficult (not to say more) to express formally.
If we let $x=10^{-n}$, it seems that a decent approximation could be
$$ \Phi^{-1}(x) - \Phi^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\sim \frac 1 {3 \sqrt n}\qquad \text{with} \qquad x=10^{-n}$$
Edit
Notice that , still with $x=10^{-n}$, asymptotically
$$ \Bigg(\Phi^{-1}(x)\Bigg)^2 -  \Bigg(\Phi^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \Bigg)^2=\log \left(\frac{4 \log \left(2 \pi  10^{-2
   n}\right)}{\log \left(\frac{1}{2} \pi 
   10^{-2 n}\right)}\right)$$ and
$$  \Bigg(\frac{\Phi^{-1}(x) }{ \Phi^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)} \Bigg)^2 \sim \frac{1579}{1139}-\frac{33}{109\, n}$$ These two relations would allow several uses.

Thank you so much for your help! Could you maybe enlighten be a bit on how you find these approximations?

@kritscosta. Just looking at the numbers for the first approximation. The first formula in the edit is purely theoretical and the second one is the result of a quick and dirty regression. If you make $x=10^{-150}$, the exact value is $0.0264819$ while the approximation gives $0.017936$. I shall try to make it better.
